# nginx *104 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-403

I have setup the following ngnix config for my Ubuntu

```
server {
    server_name server ;
    return 301 $scheme://server$request_uri;
}
server {

    server_name server;
    root /var/www/server;
    index index.html index.htm index.php ;

    location / {
      #  try_files   $uri  /index.php?$query_string;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    if (!-d $request_filename) {
            rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

}
```

I've looked at Nginx 403 forbidden for all files but that didn't help.

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: I did some changes and now im getting **FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream**

Comment: If the path in your error message is different from the `root` value in your `server` block, it means that is not the `server` block that Nginx is using. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included file and ensure that the correct `server` block is present. Also, the configuration in your question appears to have two server blocks with identical server names listening on port 80, which is not possible.